# how to execute privileged commands at system startup

Tags: 11.10, configuration, startup, thinkpad, scripts

I'm using ubuntu 11.10 on Thinkpad. Every time the system starts, I have to run the following scripts with 'sudo' to configure the device manually.

```
#setting trackpoint
TrackpointDevicePath="/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio4/serio5/"

#set speed
echo 255 > ${TrackpointDevicePath}speed

#set sensitivity
echo 255 > ${TrackpointDevicePath}sensitivity

#adust screen brightness
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

#disable touchpad
synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

I tried to put these commands in /etc/rc.local. But it didn't work because it needs root to run the commands.
Anyone can help me to run the privileged commands at system startup automatically?
Or is there any convenient gui tool for device setting which can remember the settings?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `/etc/sysctl.conf` instead.

(Or `/etc/sysctl.d/` directory to put config files there)

But you should slightly change the syntax of your configuration.

Comment: If you need detailed instructions, please, let me know.